# External User Access to Site Collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to share a Site Collection to external user outside of the organisation.

The feature is enabled at tenant level as well as site level:

Tenant Level Config:

[image]

Site Level Config:

[image]

However I still can't add the users in "People and Groups" and or Invite users to the Document Library.

Anything I've missed?? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the users who added to invite people dialog have a Microsoft account or a work or school account from another Office 365 subscription. And checked “require sign-in”.

Make sure the users sign in with the Microsoft account though the link in the invitation email.

More information refer to the article below:

[Turn external sharing on or off for SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-SharePoint-Online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30#ID0EAABAAA=Tenant_(global))

[Manage external sharing for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85#__turn_external_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I had created a Mail Contact within our Exchange Admin Center for the external user I was testing with - this was somehow conflicting when trying to share with the user.

I tested this with a different external user - which worked. I then removed the initial users "Mail Contact" -> re tried and this worked.

So something to note - having a mail contact for an external user can conflict when trying to share a site and or document library...